# Angular ngIf string is blank

Tags: angular

I need to show div when string values are greater than 3

Example

```
 <div class="block_container" *ngIf="benefit.ppc">
   <div class="bloc1">Psychiatric In-Patient Care: </div>
   <div class="bloc2">{{benefit.ppc || 'N/A' }}</div>
 </div>
```

benefit.ppc value is "ppc":"ABCD" when its "" i dont need to show the div

This is how i am fetching data

```
  this.api.getBenefits(this.company_id, this.plan).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.benefit = data.records[0];
  })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `*ngIf="value.length > 3"` and you have spelt `length` wrong in your example.

Comment: You have a typo: "legth" instead of "length".

Comment: typo close the question

Comment: Sorry update my question i need to hide the div if benef.ppc value is "" blank

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="block_container" *ngIf="(benefit.ppc).length >3">
   <div class="bloc1">Psychiatric In-Patient Care: </div>
   <div class="bloc2">{{benefit.ppc || 'N/A' }}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks updated my question i need to hide the div if the value is empty string

Comment: div should show only if benefit.ppc lenght > 3 or it should show if it takes a single value also

Comment: Thanks but dont know why its showing error on page loading ppc is not defined. I edit my question with my console also.

Comment: where is ppc inside the console, benefit.ppc gives undefined i think

Comment: its below in console

Comment: its showing value in benefit.ppc but when trying to use in ngIf its showing error

Comment: Cannot read property 'ppc' of undefined. And when i remove ngIf="benefit" only its showing value but when i use ngIf="benefit.ppc" its showing error

Comment: its because benefit.ppc is not there console.log(benefit.ppc) nd chk

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare it directly against an empty string. Try the following

```js
<div class="block_container" *ngIf="benefit.ppc && benefit.ppc !== ''">
  <div class="bloc1">Psychiatric In-Patient Care: </div>
  <div class="bloc2">{{benefit.ppc || 'N/A' }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but dont know why its showing error on page loading ppc is not defined. I edit my question with my console also.

Comment: its showing value in benefit.ppc but when trying to use in ngIf its showing error

Comment: `undefined` error is thrown because before the value is assigned to `benifit` variable, `benifit.ppc` is actually undefined. You could work around the issue by explicitly checking if the `ppc` property is defined. I've updated the `*ngIf` condition. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: How are you defining `benefit` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Let say, if you want to hide if there is no value, you should use `*ngIf="benefit?.ppc"` to avoid null or undefined issues as well. If you want to check length, you can use this `*ngIf="benefit?.ppc?.length > 3"`

like

```
<div class="block_container" *ngIf="benefit?.ppc?.length >= 2">
  <div class="bloc1">Psychiatric In-Patient Care:</div>
  <div class="bloc2">{{benefit.ppc || 'N/A' }}</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="block_container" *ngIf="benefit?.ppc">
      <div class="bloc1">Psychiatric In-Patient Care:</div>
      <div class="bloc2">{{benefit.ppc || 'N/A' }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but dont know why its showing error on page loading ppc is not defined. I edit my question with my console also.

Comment: what error do you see, if possible, please share a demo project on [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/)